# Parallel calls to VhfReadReportSubmit lead to Stack Overflow BSOD

Tags: windows, driver, hid, kmdf, bsod

I am writing a windows kmdf driver for a virtual HID device using the [vhf framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/virtual-hid-framework--vhf-). The device takes any write reports submitted to it, modifies them slightly, and spits them out via [`VhfReadReportSubmit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/vhf/nf-vhf-vhfreadreportsubmit). Unfortunately, I am getting stack-overflow BSODs when multiple reports come in parallel. I should note that I am relying on the vhf framework to buffer the submitted reports (this is the default) and thus, per documentation, there should be no restrictions on calling the `VhfReadReportSubmit` function.

The relevant code from `AddDevice` which calls `VhfCreate`:

```
    DeviceCtx* ctx = getCtx(device);
    ctx->parallel_ops_counter = 0;
    

    VHF_CONFIG_INIT(&vhfCfg, WdfDeviceWdmGetDeviceObject(device), sizeof(report_desc), report_desc);
    vhfCfg.VhfClientContext = ctx;
    vhfCfg.OperationContextSize = MAX_HID_REPORT_SIZE;
    vhfCfg.EvtVhfAsyncOperationWriteReport = ForwardReport;
    vhfCfg.VendorID = VENDOR_ID;
    vhfCfg.ProductID = PRODUCT_ID;

    status = VhfCreate(&vhfCfg, &ctx->vhfHandle);
```

and the `ForwardReport` function, which gets called when someone sumbits a write report to the device (I've removed some trace messages for simplicity):

```
// FIXME: Submitting a lot of HID reports in parallel leads to a bugcheck (BSOD)
void ForwardReport(DeviceCtx* devCtx, VHFOPERATIONHANDLE op, void* opCtx, PHID_XFER_PACKET report) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(opCtx);
    NTSTATUS status;
    HID_XFER_PACKET packet_copy;

    // Prevent BSOD (STACK_OVERFLOW) which for some unknown reason
    // happens when too many HID reports are submitted in parallel
    if (devCtx->parallel_ops_counter > MAX_PARALLEL_OPS) {
        VhfAsyncOperationComplete(op, STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES); // STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
        return;
    }
    
    devCtx->parallel_ops_counter++;

    // Copy the report to a temporary buffer
    if (report->reportBufferLen > MAX_HID_REPORT_SIZE) {
        VhfAsyncOperationComplete(op, STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW);
        return;
    }
    packet_copy.reportBuffer = opCtx;
    packet_copy.reportBufferLen = report->reportBufferLen;
    packet_copy.reportId = report->reportId;
    memcpy(opCtx, report->reportBuffer, report->reportBufferLen);
    
    // Change the report channel
    Packet* pkt = (Packet*)(packet_copy.reportBuffer);
    if (IS_CLIENT_CHANNEL(pkt->channel)) {
        pkt->channel = ENCODE_CLIENT_CHANNEL(pkt->channel);
    } else if(IS_CONTROL_CHANNEL(pkt->channel)) {
        pkt->channel = DECODE_CLIENT_CHANNEL(pkt->channel);
    }
    else if (pkt->channel == BROADCAST_CHANNEL_SERVER) {
        pkt->channel = BROADCAST_CHANNEL_CLIENT;
    }
    else if (pkt->channel == BROADCAST_CHANNEL_CLIENT) {
        pkt->channel = BROADCAST_CHANNEL_SERVER;
    }

    // Submit the changed report
    status = VhfReadReportSubmit(devCtx->vhfHandle, &packet_copy);

    // Set the operation return code
    VhfAsyncOperationComplete(op, status);
    
    devCtx->parallel_ops_counter--;
}
```

If I remove the `MAX_PARALLEL_OPS` check, the driver regularly results in a BSOD. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: how did you define your IO queue? I think that your VhfReadReportSubmit() cause a Recursion

Comment: @Baget I don't; I expect that the vhf framework does that for me when I am not doing my own buffering (plus its not mentioned in any of the examples in the docs)

Comment: IO queue is basic WDF\KMDF component it is not related to VHF